# Draw a string on a picture on WP

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to draw a string on a picture from the library on Windows Phone. To get the picture I'm using the PhotoChooserTask. After getting the picture I want to write a text of a textbox on this image and save the image to the library.

```
WriteableBitmap wbmps = new WriteableBitmap(480, 800);
wbmps.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

ScaleTransform transform = new ScaleTransform();
transform.ScaleX = 1;
transform.ScaleY = 1;

wbmps.Render(backgroundPic, transform);
wbmps.Render(diaText, transform);

wbmps.Invalidate();

backgroundPic.Source = wbmps;
```

But this do not that what I want. So how can I fix it and write something on the image. After this I want to make a colored rectangle around the text, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: what do you want? what is diaText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your elements in a Grid and then render the Grid:

```
      <Grid x:Key="TheGrid">
        <Image.../>
        <Border ...>
           <TexBlock .../>
        </Border>
      <Grid>
```

code:

```
    wbmps.Render(TheGrid, transform);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. I want to save the image completly together with the text, but now I can only save the image...

Comment: this should work, you cant try to replace the grid with a canvas, but then you have to position the elements absolutely.